# Como enviar imagenes desde React a DRF

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, djangorestframework

recién estoy haciendo mi primer proyecto `full-stack` usando `React` en el `frontend` y `Django Rest Framework` en el `backend`. Lo primero que estoy haciendo es un registro de usuarios. Pues bien, el problema viene dado por el envió de las imágenes desde el cliente al servidor, ya que pasa lo siguiente:

Código de formulario:

```
import { Header } from "../components/Header";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form"
import { createUsuario } from "../api/createUsuario.api.js";
import "../styles/signup-styles.css"
export function SignUp() {
    const {register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}} = useForm()
    const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (data) =>{
        const res = await createUsuario(data)
        return <Navigate to="signup-activate"></Navigate>
    })
    return (
        <>
        <Header/>
        <form  onSubmit={onSubmit} method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data"  > 
            {errors.username && <p>introduce el nombre de usuario pana</p>}
            {errors.email && <p>introduce el correo de usuario pana</p>}
            {errors.password && <p>introduce la contrasenia</p>}
            <label>
                Nombre de usuario:
                <input 
                    defaultValue="aly99"
                    type="text" 
                    id="nombre" 
                    name="username"
                    {...register("username", {
                        required:true
                    })}
                />
            </label>
            <label>
                Correo electrónico:
                <input 
                    defaultValue="santi@gmail.com" 
                    type="email" 
                    id="email" 
                    name="email"
                    {...register("email", {
                        required:true
                    })}
                />
            </label>
            <label>
                Contraseña : 
                <input 
                    defaultValue="16102005" 
                    type="password" 
                    id="password" 
                    name="password"
                    {...register("password", {
                        required:true
                    })}
                    />
            </label>
            <label>
                Primer(os) Nombre(s) : 
                <input 
                    defaultValue="Alayla" 
                    type="text" 
                    id="first_names" 
                    name="first_names"
                    {...register("first_names", {
                        required:true
                    })}
                    />
            </label>
            <label>
                Apellido (s): 
                <input 
                    defaultValue="Guzman" 
                    type="text" 
                    id="last_names" 
                    name="last_names"
                    {...register("last_names", {
                        required:true
                    })}
                    />
            </label>
            <label>
                Edad : 
                <input 
                    defaultValue="18" 
                    type="number" 
                    id="age" 
                    name="age"
                    {...register("age", {
                        required:true
                    })}
                    />
            </label>
            <label>
                Foto : 
                <input 
                    type="file" 
                    id="photo" 
                    name="photo"
                    {...register("photo", {
                        required:true
                    })}
                    />
            </label>
            <button type="submit">enviar</button>
        </form>
        </>
    )
}
```

Código de `createUsuario`:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { BACKEND_URL } from '../main'

export function createUsuario(data){
    return axios.post(BACKEND_URL+"api/create",data, {
        headers:
        {
            "Content-Type" : 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    } )
}
```

~ El problema exactamente se da en la parte de los `headers` cuando se llama a `axios`:

```
        headers:
        {
            "Content-Type" : 'multipart/form-data'
        }
```

~ Lo que esta pasando es que esa parte del código es necesaria para que se envíe la imagen correctamente al servidor, sin embargo, al agregar ese `header`, se cambia todo el formato de todo el resto de los campos del formulario, haciendo invalida la petición. Cual es la solucion a este problema? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

~ La solución a este problema fue no tratar de enviar las imágenes de los usuarios al `backend`, sino usar `Cloudinary` como `cloud` para almacenar las imágenes de los usuarios y almacenar en la base de datos unicamente el `link` de la imagen en si.